# Error "no Route matched with those values" with the Kong ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kong, kubernetes-networking, kong-ingress

Attempting to connect to a Jupyter Lab container (ultimately other applications as well) running on a cloud managed Kubernetes service using Kong as the ingress controller. Receiving `"no Route matched with those values"` on the http response to Kong's public IP and the ingress-controller logs indicate:

```
service kong/rjup2 does not have any active endpoints
no configuration change, skipping sync to Kong
```

Deployment Config:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: rjup2
  namespace: kong
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: rjup2
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: rjup2
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
        - name: rjup2
          image: jupyter/minimal-notebook
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8888
              protocol: TCP
```

Service Config:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:  
  name: rjup2
  namespace: kong
spec:
  selector:    
    app: rjup2
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:  
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8888
    protocol: TCP
```

Ingress Resource Config:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: rjup2
  namespace: kong
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - <AKS API server address>
  rules:
  - host: <AKS API server address>
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: rjup2
          servicePort: 80
```

The `API Server Address` is properly populated in the deployed YAML. I have tried different namespaces before consolidating them under Kong's default namespace and also tried making the service ports 8888 in addition to the containers target port.

Thanks for any assistance in debugging this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your `rjup2` `Service` doesn't have a valid selector. Note that the `Pods` you are trying to expose are labelled with `run: rjup2` label and your `Service` has `app: rjup2` selector.**

Btw. you get very clear error message that indicates where the problem could be:

```
service kong/rjup2 does not have any active endpoints
```

If your `rjup2` service in `kong` namespace doesn't have any active endpoints, it means it doesn't expose your `Pods` properly which may indicate a possible mismatch in your configuration.

You can check it by running:

```
kubectl get ep -n kong
```

Normally you should see the matching `Endpoints` object. In your case you won't see it as your `Service` cannot expose any pods untill it has a valid selector.

If you fix your `Service` definition, everything should work just fine:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:  
  name: rjup2
  namespace: kong
spec:
  selector:    
    run: rjup2
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:  
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8888
    protocol: TCP
```

Comment: Thank you. This  was the primary source of the error. Additionally, at least on Azure without a DNS hostname, the host: API Server Address information in the ingress config is not required.